# How to insert and auto remove filed unnecessary or null in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying some ways to completely delete the filed 1 when it is null when inserting data

For example: I'm 1 user A  I have name, age and country is null But I don't want it to add a country field in the database

like this

```
db.collection("user").doc().set({
    name: "A",
    age: "18",
    country: "" or country: null or country:'null'
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
```

I want it like this

Collection(user)=>randomUid=>data(name:'A',age:'18')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) and a conditional object.

```js
const country = /* ... value from form/page/etc ... */;

db.collection("user").doc()
  .set({
    name: "A",
    age: "18",
    // if country is truthy and also not "null", include it, otherwise, omit it.
    ...(country && country !== "null" ? { country } : {})
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
  })
  .catch(err => console.error) // don't forget to handle errors!
```

Comment: ... (country && country! == "null"? {country}: {}) Why not use 'country! == "null"? {country}: {} ''

Comment: Because you specified that `country` should not be included if it's value is `""`, `null` or `"null"`. If you change it to just `country !== "null"`, you allow `""` and `null` to pass through.

Comment: tks you very much